# Django how to update model fields in browser

Tags: javascript, django, database, rest

I am writing this web app which enables user to upload some set of data, and sort them into different categories, and enable to store in the server database. However, I am not sure how do I update the database when user trigger some events (say input change) in the browser? It will be great if someone can help

Say my model is just like:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And there is a table in html displaying the data, showing the name and category, and the user can dynamically change the table content.

I suppose there will be a table entry which will be a `<input>` tag

Upon any change event, I should be able to verify the change, and update the model database. Or more general some javascript events triggered and how to synchronize back to the database please?

Right now, the only way I can think of is to fire a request, and in the url includes all the information, and then have a function in the `views.py` handling in the update and finally return back the same page. But this is just not acceptable right? I am just being stupid and there must be a better way!

Comment: Why should there be a better way? That's how the web works. What you're describing is a simple Ajax interaction. You can of course just include the updated row rather than the whole table in the Ajax response, but otherwise that's exactly what you would do.

Comment: Send request -> receive it -> process it (view) -> send response...welcome to how the web works.